# Updating an existing record just created in a Callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, callback

Through a after_create callback I'm trying to assign a User a Program_id though a join model, and assign initial values for three additional parameters in that same join model.

Assigning the program_id works fine, I can't figure out how to add the additional parameters.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

after_create :assign_user_program, :add_initial_programs

  def assign_user_program
    self.programs = Program.for_user(self)
  end

class Program < ActiveRecord:Base

  def self.for_user(user)
    where(:goal_id => user.goal_id, :experience_id => user.experience_level_id, :gender => user.gender) 
  end
```

I tried creating another method in the after_create to assign the other three parameters, but that just creates another record in the join model with the three parameters assigned, and no program_id

```
def add_initial_programs
   self.user_programs.create(:cycle_order => 1, :group_order => 1, :workout_order => 1)
end
```

Any ideas on how I can simply update the record that was just created?

EDIT:

To clarify, I'm trying to create one record in the join table with the program_id, user_id, group_order, cycle_order, and workout_order, as shown in the picture:

[image]

What is happening is that I'm getting two records, one with a program_id, and one with no program_id, but the other values assigned. See picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer here was actually quite simple. I needed to put all the logic into one method like this:

```
def add_initial_program
    prog_id = Program.for_user(self).first.id
    self.user_programs.build( :cycle_order => 1, :group_order => 1, :workout_order => 1, :program_id => prog_id)
  end
```

Which created the desired result of giving a user a program, and assigning the other values I needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably run your callback `before_create` instead of `after_create` so the extra attributes get set on the model before it's persisted to the database. Doing it `after_create` means you'll end up sending two queries (one `CREATE` and one `UPDATE`) instead of one `CREATE`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :assign_user_program, :add_initial_programs

  protected

  def assign_user_program
    self.programs = Program.for_user(self)
  end

  def add_initial_programs
    self.user_programs.build(:cycle_order => 1, :group_order => 1, :workout_order => 1)
  end
end
```

If you really want to do it in `after_create`, you'll have to call `save` or `save!` on the user model to actually persist the attribute changes to the database.

Comment: Save is an undefined method `save' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation, and before_create can't work because You cannot call create unless the parent is saved

Comment: I meant call `save!` on the user model. You need to use `build` instead of `create` to build the join models if the parent record doesn't exist yet. I added some sample code to clarify.

Comment: That works, but I'm back to the original problem of two records being created.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what behavior you're expecting without further details. Maybe you should clarify in the question what "user_programs" is and which two records are getting created.

Comment: I just updated the question. user_programs is just a table of the programs a user has been assigned. The most recent record for a user is the current program a user has. Make sense?